# Java HashMap: A Bug in JVM or I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, hashmap

In the code below:-

1. Create the HashMap and add some elements.
2. Create second HashMap taking the mapping of first.
3. Modify the second HashMap.
4. First HashMap is modified along with?

   ```
   public static void test(){
       HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> testData = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> ();
       testData.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(777)));
       System.out.println(testData);
       HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> testData1 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> (testData);
       testData1.get(1).add(888);
       System.out.println(testData);
   }
   ```

**Output:**

```
{1=[777]}
{1=[777, 888]}
```

Try it here: [Code on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/JJTcHO)

I expected both testData and testData1 to be independent of each other, but it seems like both of them refer to same object? Is it intended in Java? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is intended.  The map is only storing *references*, not objects.

Comment: Oh! so It means two map objects but containing same ArrayList? How to resolve this?

Do I need to manually create another copy of array? Cloning is not making fresh copy of ArrayList. Same issue persists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a *shallow copy* of the original `HashMap`:
the list references are copied, then their items.

You need to do a *deep copy* yourself:

```
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> testData = new HashMap<>();
    testData.put(1, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(777)));

    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> testData = new HashMap<>();
    testData.put(1, Arrays.asList(777));

    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> testData2 = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : testData.entrySet()) {
        testData2.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    testData2.get(1).add(888);
    System.out.println(testData);
    System.out.println(testData2);
```

This prints:

> ```
> {1=[777]}
> {1=[777, 888]}
> ```

As [@jon-kiparsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405303/jon-kiparsky) explained nicely in a comment:

> This may be obvious, but just for completeness: since a HashMap stores objects, not primitives, your maps store references to objects. This is why you need to think in terms of deep and shallow copies.

And as a side note, I also improved your example code:

- Use interface types in declarations instead of implementation types
- No need to wrap `Arrays.asList(...)` inside a `new ArrayList<>(...)`
- Use the diamond operator `<>` in Java 7 (and consequently use Java 7 or later as older versions are no longer supported)

Comment: This may be obvious, but just for completeness: since a HashMap stores objects, not primitives, your maps store references to objects. This is why you need to think in terms of deep and shallow copies.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood. It was kind of unintuitive to me. So there is no shorthand of deep copying in Java?

I mean there has to be a function where it makes copies for both the object and the objects it contain

Comment: Thanks @JonKiparsky, you said it so well I included in my answer verbatim ;-)

Comment: @MangatRai in the Java SDK I don't think so. In utility libraries like Apache or Google's Guava probably there are utility classes to make this easier.

Comment: I thought HashMap(HashMap e) constructor will do a deep copy. Thanks for the recommendations...

Answer (score 0):

All the collections in java hold refrences to object. So, while you are modifying list from second map, it is modifying the same object of list